# Why do parentheses create a left-recursion?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

The following grammar works fine:

```
grammar DBParser;
statement: expr EOF;
expr: expr '+' expr | Atom;
Atom: [a-z]+ | [0-9]+ ;
```

[image]

However, neither of the following do:

```
grammar DBParser;
statement: expr EOF;
expr: (expr '+' expr) | Atom;
Atom: [a-z]+ | [0-9]+ ;
```

```
grammar DBParser;
statement: expr EOF;
expr: (expr '+' expr | Atom);
Atom: [a-z]+ | [0-9]+ ;
```

[image]

Why does antlr4 raise an error when adding in parentheticals, does that somehow change the meaning of the production that is being parsed?

Comment: To me that looks like a bug in the code to detect mutually left recursive rules. Try opening a bug report in the ANTLR4 repo on Github.

Comment: This is a well-known issue for many years. https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/564. Just remove useless parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parentheses create a subrule, and subrules are handled internally by treating them as though they were new productions (in effect anonymous, which is why the mutual recursion error message only lists one non-terminal).

In these particular examples, the subrule is pointless; the parentheses could simply be removed without altering the grammar. But apparently Antlr doesn't attempt to decide which subrules are actually serving a purpose. (I suppose it could, but I wonder if it's a common enough usage to make justify the additional code complexity. But it's certainly not up to me to decide.)

Comment: thanks again for your answer here. Are you available to do outside consulting on grammar-related issues? We have a formal grammar for our SQL and it seems you're an expert in this and it'd be great to have you provide your expertise on this. If so, if you could drop your email and I can message you outside (and then you can remove it after I email you) that'd be great.